# How to display items loading while data is being fetched from Firebase android kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` and my `Fragment`. I am getting data from `Firebase Realtime Database` into a RecyclerView.

I need to make it so that while the data is loading, I see some kind of loading effect. How can i do this?

Code from my `Fragment:`

```
private var _binding: FragmentDayDetailBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

private var ref: DatabaseReference? = null
private lateinit var adapter: DayDetailAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentDayDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    setupRecyclerView()
    initDatabase()

    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    readFromDatabase()
}

private fun setupRecyclerView() {
    adapter = DayDetailAdapter()
    binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}

private fun initDatabase() {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(requireContext())

    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("IMIT")
        .child("groups")
}

private fun readFromDatabase() {
    ref?.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {

                val list = ArrayList<Day>()

                for (daySnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val day = daySnapshot.getValue(Day::class.java)

                    list.add(day!!)
                }

                adapter.submitList(list)

            } else {
                binding.apply {
                    lrDbEmpty.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    recyclerView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Code from `RecyclerView Adapter:`

```
class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemSubjectDetailBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(day: Day) = with(binding) {
        tvSubject.text = day.subject
        tvInfo.text = "${day.teacher}, ${day.type}"
        tvTime.text = day.time
        tvAud.text = day.classroom
    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = ItemSubjectDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder.from(parent)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    with(holder) {
        bind(getItem(position))
    }
}

class ItemComparator: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Day>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Day, newItem: Day): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Day, newItem: Day): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I also think that this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp) might help.

Comment: @AlexMamo wow, this repo will help me a lot, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already in half the way

Create a [progressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar) in the center of the fragment

```
<ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
```

Keep it visible until the data fetched (`onDataChange` Called) then hide the progressBar

```
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        // rest of your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a dynamic add view.
I use the lottie player for the show wait animation. There are two approaches for adding the show wait. In this way, you can add animation or any type of view from the non-activity class. It helps you to better implement in the MVVM form.
This is both methods implementation.

1- Create and remove by Id
2- Create and remove by LiveData

```
class AddViewNonActivity(
private val viewGroup: ViewGroup
) {
fun addCustomWait(): Int {
    val relativeLayout =
        RelativeLayout(viewGroup.context)
    val relativeParams =
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
    val lottieParams =
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(600, 600)
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(
        viewGroup.context.getColor(R.color.wait_transparent)
    )
    relativeLayout.gravity = CENTER
    val lottieLoading = LottieAnimationView(viewGroup.context)
    lottieLoading.setAnimation("lottie/space-runner.json")
    lottieLoading.repeatCount = INFINITE
    lottieLoading.speed = 1f
    lottieLoading.playAnimation()
    relativeLayout.addView(lottieLoading, lottieParams)
    val viewId = View.generateViewId()
    viewGroup.addView(relativeLayout, relativeParams)
    relativeLayout.id = viewId
    relativeLayout.isClickable = true
    return viewId
}

fun removeCustomWait(
    waitViewId: Int
) {
    for (view in viewGroup) {
        if (view.id == waitViewId)
            viewGroup.removeView(view)
    }
}

fun addLiveCustomWait(
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    liveData: LiveData<Boolean>) {
    var viewId = 0
    liveData.observe(lifecycleOwner) {
        if (it) {
            removeCustomWait(viewId)
            viewId = addCustomWait()
        } else {
            removeCustomWait(viewId)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Activity call method

```
class DynamicViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding : ActivityDynamicViewBinding
private val liveShowWait =MutableLiveData(false)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityDynamicViewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    var waitId = 0
    initialWait()

    binding.btnAddView.setOnClickListener {
        waitId = AddViewNonActivity(binding.root).addCustomWait()
    }

    binding.btnRemoveView.setOnClickListener {
        AddViewNonActivity(binding.root).removeCustomWait(waitId)
    }

    binding.btnLiveAddView.setOnClickListener {
        liveShowWait.postValue(true)
    }

    binding.btnLiveRemoveView.setOnClickListener {
        liveShowWait.postValue(false)
    }
}

private fun initialWait() =
    AddViewNonActivity(binding.root).addLiveCustomWait(this as 
LifecycleOwner, liveShowWait)
}
```

[Github link](https://github.com/alidoran/KotlinReferences/tree/master/android/src/main/java/alidoran/android/add_dynamic_view)